# ONNX to Tensorflow 2: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow 2.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.
I converted an ONNX model to Tensorflow 2 .pb format with the below code:

```
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

model_path="my_model/model.onnx"
output_path="my_model/model.pb"

onnx_model = onnx.load(model_path)
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)
tf_rep.export_graph(output_path)
```

Then I tried reading the converted .pb file with:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model_dir = "my_model"

model = tf.saved_model.load(model_dir)
print(model.summary())
```

I got the following error
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 89: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 89: invalid start byte in field: tensorflow.MetaGraphDef.MetaInfoDef.meta_graph_version`

How do I fix this? Tried googling but the answers I found are all for TF 1 which either read with `"rb"` mode or decode with `"utf8"`, but both options are not available in TF 2's `tf.saved_model.load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer to my problem, but I managed to test the codes on a different hardware with similar software setup and it works.
So perhaps the original hardware I was working on had some corrupted libraries...